# d3.js create missing nodes with stratify

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a sunburst chart starting from the leaf nodes, where the hierarchy is encoded in a path format:

```
leaves = [ {key: '/path/to/A'},
           {key: '/path/to/B'},
           {key: '/link/C'} ];
```

To draw the sunburst, I need either an already nested object to pass to d3.hierachy, or a flat array of nodes *already containining the interior nodes* to pass to d3.stratify.
I.e. to use stratify I would need

```
leaves = [ {key: '/path/to/A'},
           {key: '/path/to/B'},
           {key: '/link/C'},
           {key: '/'},
           {key: '/path'},
           {key: '/path/to'},
           {key: '/link'} ];
```

Figuring out those extra nodes for an arbitrary hierarchy is redoing half the work that stratify does in the first place! Am I missing something, or should I just give up and do it manually?  Any suggestions for an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Check out this burrow function: https://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/eebcb592d3fdd9ac4a5c92361c1e7066